# Facebook login with ionic v1

Tags: android, angularjs, facebook, ionic-framework, oauth

I'm trying to develop an ionic app using facebook login. But I got some issues with Facebook configuration.

I'm using this GitHub project (https://github.com/chanusukarno/Angular-Ionic-OAuth) as example and I'd configured the Facebook app into https://developers.facebook.com.

The problem is: in my localhost it works fine, since I set the **Valid OAuth redirect URIs**  with localhost:8100 as value.

But, when I try to test in my device it does not work. I got a message like that: **can't load url the domain of this url isn't included in the app's domains**.

I need to know how I configure Facebook for my device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add product in your developer console and configure it like this:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried this approach. When I use the http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html URL I have this error message: **Success 
SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone. See the Facebook Help Center for more information.**

Comment: You don't need to open that link but rather just add it in Valid OAuth Redirect URL.It works fine for me.

Comment: You are right, but my app opens it when call facebook. That's the problem, I guess.

Comment: I'm using this project as example. You can see the controller [here](https://github.com/chanusukarno/Angular-Ionic-OAuth/blob/master/www/js/controllers/controllers.js)

Comment: Try this one instead: https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

Comment: I'm trying to make this plugin works but I'm facing with a thousand of errors. But my question is, can't I have a native login without plugins and tools?

Comment: I don't know if cordova provides that.

Comment: Got it. That's ok. I could make this plugin works but the I had this mesasge again: " can't load url the domain of this url isn't included in the app's domains".

Comment: Have you configured the facebook developer's console correctly as mentioned in the image above?

Comment: Yes, the configuration is the same. URLs: https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html, http://localhost:8100 and http://localhost/callback

Comment: Should I add a platform, like android, in facebook settings or it is not necessary?

Comment: Yeah you have to add the android package name from your config.xml and in addition generate a key hash for your android app to configure for facebook app android